# Trouble connecting css sheet to html file - using textedit

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create my first website, but I am having trouble connecting the css sheet to the html file. The css file is in the same folder. I don't know what could be the issue.

```css
h1 {
  color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel=“stylesheet” type="text/css"href=“main.css”>
  <title>PCJCPWC</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    </h1>Pentecostal Church of Jesus Christ</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Ministries</li>
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>Calendar</li>
      <li>Listen</li>
      <li>Donate</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </h3>Welcome!</h3>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're missing the `<html>` openning tag. Are you sure your css and html are in the same directory? it shoudl be unslashed for the opening tags

Comment: You need to use straight quotes, not curly ones. Run your HTML through a validator such as the one at https://validator.w3.org. That will also show you your incorrect use of the `h1` tag, which should be `<h1>...</h1>` (no slash used in opening tag).

Comment: In TextEdit, uncheck the "Use smart quotes and dashes" checkbox. Google "TextEdit curly quotes" for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Try this html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel=“stylesheet” type="text/css"href=“main.css”/>
  <title>PCJCPWC</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Pentecostal Church of Jesus Christ</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Ministries</li>
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>Calendar</li>
      <li>Listen</li>
      <li>Donate</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </h3>Welcome!</h3>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't fix the problem. Did you test it?

Answer (score -1):

By the looks of your code, `<link rel=“stylesheet” type="text/css"href=“main.css”/>`, it is done right way it should be but do you have the "main.css" in the same folder that your page, ".html", is on? Also the other people are right, the opening tags that you are putting are ending tags not opening tags; just take the "/" out of them from the begining.

Ex.
`<h3></h3>`, `<title></title>`, `<html></html>` or `<!DOCTYPE html></html>`.

Comment: This won't fix the problem. Did you test it?

Comment: Try this (I prefer Chrome & know how to see the code, elements), open your browser preferably chrome and open your page, one done do Ctrl+U, for chrome. Now find the <link rel=“stylesheet” type="text/css"href=“main.css”/>. If the "main.css" shows up blue with a blue line under it and you can open it and see the code that you have written or gotten, it's properly link to your page. Now if the CSS does not change anything that you want in your page it may be because you either started your CSS file wrong or added the wrong "class", "id", etc. Hope this works!

Comment: Yes, and if you do this, you will see the `href` attribute displayed as `href="“main.css”"`, which should provide a clue to the problem already identified in the comments.

Comment: I followed your instructions and "main.css" was blue with a blue liner under it but when I opened it to see the code, it said the file was not found, although it is in the same folder.

Comment: Could it possibly be that you spelled it wrong when you linked it to your page?

Answer (score -2):

Your HTML syntax is wrong, opening tags must not contain slash at the beginning:

```
<h1>...</h1>
<h3>...</h3>
```

```css
h1 {
  color: purple;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link rel=“stylesheet” type="text/css"href=“main.css”/>
  <title>PCJCPWC</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Pentecostal Church of Jesus Christ</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Ministries</li>
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>Calendar</li>
      <li>Listen</li>
      <li>Donate</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <h3>Welcome!</h3>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have made those changes but the code still doesn't work.

Comment: This won't fix the problem. Did you test it?